# InvalidStateError when drawing SVG to canvas in Firefox (works in Chrome)

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, firefox, svg

My code works perfectly in Chrome, but throws errors in Firefox. The console says:

```
InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable
```

This is my code:

```
glitchElement('http://naratif.jvitasek.cz/images/past-no-b.svg', 'canvas1');
glitchElement('http://naratif.jvitasek.cz/images/medialni-no-b.svg', 'canvas2');
glitchElement('http://naratif.jvitasek.cz/images/subverz-no-b.svg', 'canvas3');
function glitchElement(sourceImg, idCanvas) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById(idCanvas),
        context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        img = new Image(),
        w,
        h,
        offset,
        glitchInterval;

    img.src = sourceImg;
    img.onload = function() {
        init();
        window.onresize = init;
        redraw();
    };

    var init = function() {
        clearInterval(glitchInterval);
        canvas.width = w = window.innerWidth;
        offset = w * 0.1;
        canvas.height = h = ~~(230 * ((w - (offset * 2)) / img.width));
        glitchInterval = setInterval(function() {
            clear();
            console.log(offset);
            console.log(w - (offset*2));
            console.log(h);
            context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, 230, offset, 0, w - (offset * 2), h);
            glitchImg();
            setTimeout(function() {
                clear();
                redraw();
            }, randInt(100,130)); // doba, po kterou je obrazek glitchnut
        }, randInt(3000,7000)); // interval mezi kazdym glitchem
    };

    var clear = function() {
        context.rect(0, 0, w, h);
        context.fillStyle = "white";
        context.fill();
    };

    var glitchImg = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < randInt(1, 7); i++) {
            var x = Math.random() * w;
            var y = Math.random() * h;
            var spliceWidth = w - x;
            var spliceHeight = randInt(5, h / 3);
            context.drawImage(canvas, 0, y, spliceWidth, spliceHeight, x, y, spliceWidth, spliceHeight);
            context.drawImage(canvas, spliceWidth, y, x, spliceHeight, 0, y, x, spliceHeight);
        }
    };

    var randInt = function(a, b) {
        return ~~(Math.random() * (b - a) + a);
    };

    function redraw() {
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, 230, offset, 0, w - (offset * 2), h);
    }
}
```

I read this might be a bug in Firefox, but I tried some methods to fix this (like adding width/height, canvg, ...) and nothing seems to work for me. Could anyone please hint me how to solve this so the code runs in Firefox as well?

Comment: Try giving the SVG images width and height attributes on the outer SVG element that have values that are not percentages.

Comment: @RobertLongson So if I'm drawing into a canvas, should I set width and height to that element? I'm having trouble understanding what you mean by the outer SVG element.

Comment: the root `<svg>` element in each svg file. So make the files <svg width="<some value that is not a percentage>" height="<some value that is not a percentage>"...

Comment: @RobertLongson The thing is, when I look into my source code, I don't see any SVG element. All I see is the canvas and no element inside it.

Comment: I see three, this one http://naratif.jvitasek.cz/images/past-no-b.svg and this one http://naratif.jvitasek.cz/images/medialni-no-b.svg and this one http://naratif.jvitasek.cz/images/subverz-no-b.svg

Comment: @RobertLongson Oh, so I need to open the SVG in my code editor and edit the outer SVG element to contain the width and height, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99614/discussion-between-robert-longson-and-user3710031).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for [drawImage to work with an SVG image in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=700533) the SVG image file must have a root `<svg>` element that has both width and height attributes, neither of which can be percentages.